# Sorting words in a character array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, character

For the given array, I need to write a function to sort words alphabetically:

```
char strings [][10] = {
    "hello",
    "world",
    "computers",
    "are",
    "awesome"
};
```

I've tried to write the function `sortWords` by using insertion sort, but I think my swap function isn't working:

```
void swap(char *e1, char *e2) {
    int tmp = *e1;
    *e1 = *e2;
    *e2 = tmp;
}

void sortWords( char (* words2Darray)[10], unsigned short length ) {
    unsigned int i, curPos;
    char curChars[10];

    for(i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        // Copy the current word into curChars
        strncpy_s(curChars, words2Darray[i], 10);
        curPos = i;

        // Compare and move the word to the correct position
        while(curPos > 0 && strcmp(curChars, words2Darray[i-1]) > 0) {
            swap(words2Darray[curPos], words2Darray[curPos-1]);
            curPos--;
        }
    }
}
```

I've attempted debugging my code using the Local Windows Debugger and found that `curChars` is being copied properly.

Can someone please *explain* to me what I am doing wrong and how I should go about solving this problem? I'm not allowed to use `std::string` in this problem. **No full solutions please!**

Comment: I noticed your "I'm not allowed to use std::string in this problem" clause only moments ago. Have amended my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(std::begin(strings), std::end(strings), cmp);
```

This requires a comparator. I whipped one up based on `strcmp`.

See it **[Live on IdeOne](http://ideone.com/Dsce2d)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char const* strings[] = {
        "hello",
        "world",
        "computers",
        "are",
        "awesome"
    };

    struct { 
        bool operator()(char const* a, char const* b) const {
            return (a && b)? 0 > strcmp(a,b) : a < b;
        }
    } cmp;

    std::sort(std::begin(strings), std::end(strings), cmp);

    for (auto& s : strings)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Note that I took the liberty of making the array elements `char*` instead of `char[]`. 
This is for the reasons pointed out by Carl Norum.

Comment: C++ code can be insidious. The std::less comparison converts both char* arguments into strings, compares them, then discards the strings. This is a great example of a small line of code that has bigger than expected performance implications.

Comment: @ZanLynx True that. I wrote the last line for a reason. I'm not about to recommend a custom comparator for `char(&)[]` only to add that swap must be provided too. In case the OP needs contiguous storage, I'm going to assume he/she will get to grips with these aspects of C++ first. ***Profiling before everything***

Comment: I was basically being clever in order to be <strike>lazy</strike> effective. There are situations where you'll want more performance. My 10 bucks says _this_ is not such a situation :)

Comment: @ZanLynx Anyways, I changed it around, now it doesn't use `std::string` at all, anymore

Comment: Years later someone took the time to downvote this. I guess that was without reading the comments. Oh well. Can't delete the accepted answer :/

Answer (score 1):

You're not swapping strings, you're swapping the first characters of strings.  If you want to pass by value, you need something like:

```
void swap(char **e1, char **e2) {
    char *tmp = *e1;
    *e1 = *e2;
    *e2 = tmp;
}
```

And then to use it:

```
swap(&words2Darray[curPos], &words2Darray[curPos-1]);
```

Alternately you can leave the `swap` call as-is and use references:

```
void swap(char *&e1, char *&e2) {
    char *tmp = e1;
    e1 = e2;
    e2 = tmp;
}
```

(I think that's right - my C++ is rusty.  I'll make a test to be sure.)

Comment: The program won't compile now: `Error C2664: 'swap' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [10]' to 'char *&'`

Comment: Yeah, you have other bugs too.  Passing pointers to arrays around is pretty weird.